# @arcgis/core delete graphic

Tags: react

I have an NextJS app using `@arcgis/core` based `WebMap` using a `SketchViewModel`, which is used when I click a custom button to draw a polygon on the map. That all works fine, the problem arises when I want to remove the graphic. I have another custom button that gets the layer from the map and calls the `layer.removeAll()` function, but it doesn't alway remove the graphic, until I move the map, then it is removed.

I have tried:

- Remove the graphic from the GraphicsLayer `layer.removeAll()`
- Remove the graphic by specifying the layer `map.findLayerById('DRAWING').removeAll()`
- Remove the graphics from the view `view.graphics.removeAll()`
- Remove the layer from the map `map.remove(layer)`

I have all of these  together in my hook at one time and still the graphic is visible until I move the map.

Here is my actual hook:

```
export const useDeleteDrawing = () => {
  const { view } = useMap();

  const deleteDrawing = () => {
    if (view) {
      const lyr = view.map.findLayerById(DRAWING_LAYER_ID) as GraphicsLayer;
      view.graphics.removeAll();
      lyr.removeAll();
      view.map.layers.forEach((element) => {
        console.log('ELEMENT: ', element);
        if (element.graphics) {
          element.graphics.removeAll();
        }
      });
    }
  };

  return { deleteDrawing };
};
```

Does anyone have any ideas, as I've been at this all day and cannot see any solution.